# Why would you want to create more than one event loops in asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Why not just use the default one always? are there any usecases for creating multiple event loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason behind your question.
But there are certainly use cases for using multiple loops. e.g. To increase scalability.

We know, CPU-bound code will interfere with event-loops in a process. This will reduce throughput.

Not if we have loops in other processes, event-loops in other processes will not be disturbed. Of course we have to think about locking mechanisms etc. If using `asyncio` with `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is multithreaded, and you want to run asyncio code in more than one thread, you absolutely need to create additional event loops.

Comment: Could you help me understand why one would need to use multithreading when already using asyncio ? given that both are restricted to same core due to GIL

Comment: @D.B.K If code in a single-threaded asyncio program blocks the thread, other tasks cannot run.  Examples would be I/O, or any time the program waits for an external resource without using an await expression.  In a multithreaded program, one thread can block while other threads continue.  It depends entirely on what you are trying to do.  Sometimes I've read on this site that you should not use threads and asyncio together, but there are situations where that's just what you need (and the asyncio package supports it).  Sometimes the asyncio package launches extra threads under the hood.